# Specifying tree_method param for XGBoost in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm working on a predictive model using XGBoost (latest version on PyPl: 0.6) in Python, and have been developing it training on about half of my data. Now that I have my final model, I trained it on all my data, but got this message, which I've never seen before:

> Tree method is automatically selected to be 'approx' for faster speed.
>   to use old behavior(exact greedy algorithm on single machine), set
>   tree_method to 'exact'"

As a reproduceable example, the following code also produces that message on my machine:

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb

rows = 10**7
cols = 20
X = np.random.randint(0, 100, (rows, cols))    
y = np.random.randint(0,2, size=rows)

clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=5)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

I've tried setting tree_method to 'exact' in both the initialization and `fit()` steps of my model, but each throws errors:

```
import xgboost as xgb
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(tree_method = 'exact')
clf
> __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tree_method'


my_pipeline.fit(X_train, Y_train, clf__tree_method='exact')
> self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params) TypeError: fit() got an
> unexpected keyword argument 'tree_method'
```

How can I specify tree_method='exact' with XGBoost in Python?

Comment: Looking at the [python documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.core), I cannot find any parameter named `tree_method`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the XGBoost [parameter documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest//parameter.html), this is because the default for `tree_method` is "auto".  The "auto" setting is data-dependent: for "small-to-medium" data, it will use the "exact" approach and for "very-large" datasets, it will use "approximate".  When you started to use your whole training set (instead of 50%), you must have crossed the training-size threshold that changes the auto-value for `tree_method`.  It's unclear from the docs how many observations are required to reach that threshold, but it seems that it's somewhere between 5 and 10 million rows (since you have `rows = 10**7`).

I don't know if the `tree_method` argument is exposed in the XGBoost Python module (it sounds like it's not, so maybe file a bug report?), but `tree_method` is exposed in the R API.

The docs describe why you see that warning message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is still not implemented in the scikit-learn API for xgboost. 
Hence I'm referencing the below code example from [here](https://medium.com/data-design/xgboosts-new-fast-histogram-tree-method-hist-a3c08f36234c).

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

digits = load_digits(2)
X = digits['data']
y = digits['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, y_test)

param = {'objective': 'binary:logistic',
         'tree_method':'hist',
         'grow_policy':"lossguide",
         'eval_metric': 'auc'}
res = {}
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, 10, [(dtrain, 'train'), (dtest, 'test')], evals_result=res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPU from sklearn API in xGBoost. You can use it like this:

```
import xgboost

xgb = xgboost.XGBClassifier(n_estimators=200, tree_method='gpu_hist', predictor='gpu_predictor')
xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You can use different tree methods. Refer to the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu/index.html) to choose the most appropriate methods for your need.

Comment: now its params = { "n_estimators": 400, 'tree_method':['gpu_hist'], 'predictor':['gpu_predictor'] }

Comment: He wanted to know how to apply tree_metod exact not hist.